# Buscar en una tabla

Tags: java, android

Tengo una tabla TablaTurnos.java y queria buscar un elemento (nombreseded) y que me devuelva (idseded). ¿Como lo podria hacer?

```
public class TablaTurnos {

private String idseded, nombreseded,


public TablaTurnos(String idseded, String nombreseded) {
    this.idseded = idseded;
    this.nombreseded = nombreseded;
}
public TablaTurnos() { }

public String getIdseded() {
    return idseded;
}

public void setIdseded(String idseded) {
    this.idseded = idseded;
}

public String getNombreseded() {
    return nombreseded;
}

public void setNombreseded(String nombreseded) {
    this.nombreseded = nombreseded;
}
```

La tabla la relleno (por supuesto es un bucle que hace que la tabla se relleno y no lo pongo para simplificar codigo)y decladro asi:

```
  ArrayList<TablaTurnos> ListSede;        
  ListSede = new ArrayList<>();  
       
  ListSede.add(new TablaTurnos(tidsede, tnombresede));
```

Comment: Con base a que deseas buscar el elemento

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu pregunta, tal vez esto te pueda ayudar:

```
String getId( ArrayList<TablaTurnos> ListSede, String nombreseded ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < ListSede.size(); i ++ ) { 

           // mientras recrremos la lista, le pedimos a cada "miembro" el nombre, 
           // y si es igual al buscado, retornamos el "id" respectivo
        if( ListSede.get( i ).getNombreseded().equals( nombreseded ) ) {
            return ListSede.get( i ).getIdseded();
        }
    }
       // si llegamos aquí, es que no se encontró ninguna coincidencia...
    return "No existe ese nombre";
}
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo tu lista de objetos, puedes usar el indice donde se ubica el elemento para obtenerlo.

por ejemplo para obtener el segundo elemento usas el indice 3:

```
TablaTurnos elementoTabla = ListSede.get(3);
 System.out.println(elementoTabla.getIdseded() +"|"+elementoTabla.getNombreseded());
```

Si deseas buscar un valor de alguna propiedad, por ejemplo Idseded, lo puedes realizar de esta forma realizando un bucle y buscando la coincidencia en las propiedades de la lista de objetos:

```
   String valorIdseded = "algo";//valor Idseded a buscar.

   for(TablaTurnos elementoTabla: ListSede){
      if(elementoTabla.getIdseded().equals(valorIdseded)){
         System.out.println(elementoTabla.getIdseded() +"|"+elementoTabla.getNombreseded());
         break;
      }
   }
```